# MatPlotLib Change Axis Title and Size

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

All I'm trying to do is change the name and size of the chart axis text for a Matplot plot

My Charts Class:

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.compute_initial_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

    def update_figure(self):
        l = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(4)]
        self.axes.cla()
        self.axes.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], l, 'r')
        self.draw()
```

Here is where I create the object in a different python file:

```
   def initialiseChart(self):
        theLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.widgetChart)
        self.canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.widgetChart, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        theLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.axes.set(xlabel='Year Week', ylabel='Volume',
                             title='Delivered National Letters')
        self.canvas.axes.grid()
        self.widgetChart.setFocus()
```

and this is where I do the update (failing in HERE):

```
  def updateChart(self):
        # Clear the chart
        self.canvas.axes.cla()

        chartTitle = (str(self.cmbPipeline.currentText()) + ' ' + str(self.cmbMailCentre.currentText()) + ' ' +
                      str(self.cmbFormat.currentText()))

        # Show the grid
        self.canvas.axes.grid()
        # Set the axis and chart title
        self.canvas.axes.set(xlabel='Year Week', ylabel='Volume',
                             title=chartTitle)

        # Set Font Sizes
        #self.canvas.fig.title(chartTitle)
        #self.canvas.xlabel('TEST', fontsize=12)
        #self.canvas.fig.set_xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=10)
        self.canvas.set_xlabel('x-axis')
        # self.canvas.axes.plot.ylabel('Volume', fontsize=12)
```

It just keeps telling my there is no attribute, but I thought I'm inhertiting the methods to change the axis titles so i'm confused

Comment: Your "canvas" object didn't inherit from anything with `set_xlabel`.  You want `canvas.axes.set_xlabel`.